# Cucumber JVM - Report not yet generated when attempting to send via email using @AfterClass

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber-jvm

I am attempting to gather up all the files my tests generate (log file, screenshots, cucumber report etc) and send them via email. I'm doing this from the Runner class using JUnit's @AfterClass annotation.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/Features"
    , glue = { "stepDefinition" }
    , tags = { "@Teeest" }
    , monochrome = true
    , strict = false
    , plugin = { /* "pretty", */ "html:target/cucumber-html-report","json:target/cucumber-html-report/cucumber-json-" + "report.json" })

public class TestRunner {

    @AfterClass
    public static void sendReport() {
        SomeClass.sendMail();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except for the cucumber reports (both html and json), which are blank. When i manually check it, it looks good so I'm assuming it's generated sometime after this method is executed.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can get around this issue?

I'm thinking of either getting the Cucumber Reports plugin for Jenkins, writing a shell script to execute via Maven POM or a separate Java app that looks for the files, zips and sends the email.

All 3 of these ideas come with drawbacks so I'd really love another hook-type approach to this, if possible, as file locations have dynamic names and would be a lot easier to get the actual locations within the test suite than to look for them afterward.

Thanks!

PS: I am junior at this stuff so please don't hold back on details :)

Comment: Do you really want it to send email every time you run it locally?

Comment: Hey! Well no but i can skip that action when running on local. Is that weird?

Comment: So default will be to skip? It would be better to just do it as part of CI build with a Jenkins report email plugin of some sort

Comment: As far as I know cucumber doesn't support JUnit annotations, so theoretically it's not correct way to do it. I would follow advise from above and do it rather externally, however, one solution you may want to try is to `addShutdownHook()` from `Runtime` and send your report from there